# Suppose I have a list or map in controller, so how can I access them in GSP view using render method?

Tags: grails, gsp

`def map = [name : "akshay"]` 
`def name_map = [full_name : map]` //map

`def list = ["c", "c++", "java"]` //list
        //want to render above map and list to gsp and want to display it on page

Answer (score 0):

render method accepts a map. In your controller provide the view name you want to render and a model map containing your data and then you can directly access the model map on your gsp.

```
def map = [name: "akshay"]
def name_map = [full_name: map] //map
def list = ["c", "c++", "java"] //list

render view: 'index', model: [nameMap: name_map, langList: list]
```

In your gsp, to iterate over list:

```
<g:each in="${langList}" status="index" var="lang">
    ${lang}
</g:each>
```

and to iterate over map of map:

```
<g:each in="${nameMap}" status="index" var="fullNameMap">
    ${fullNameMap.key}
    <g:each in="${fullNameMap.value}" status="subIndex" var="map">
        ${map.key}
        ${map.value}
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

Also a word of advice, if you know the datatype of a variable in advance then use the datatype instead of def.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Its working. And also thank you for your advise.

Comment: the o/p is.      full_name name akshay 
c c++ java

Comment: What I don't agree with is not using 'def'. Here's why: `def map1 = [name: 'akshay']
Map map2 = [name: 'akshay']

def list1 = ["c", "c++", "java"]
List list2 = ["c", "c++", "java"]

assert map1.getClass() == LinkedHashMap
assert map2.getClass() == LinkedHashMap

assert list1.class == ArrayList
assert list2.class == ArrayList`

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa It is always a good practice to specify a definite type for a variable. This post will make things more clear to you: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/280185

Comment: For method arguments oh yes, definitely define the type. But I find that for internal use, such as declaring a variable within a method, def is just fine.